# How to enable CORS in express server?

Tags: angular, express, cors

I have MEAN stack application with the client (live server on port 4200) and express server listening on port 5000. Now I have installed CORS and enable it, but every time the client is making a POST/GET request it ends in getting blocked.

Client:

```
  uri = 'http://localhost:5000/api';
  login (user) {
  return this.http.post(`${this.uri}/login`, user,{withCredentials: true});               
}
```

Sever:

```
  const cors = require('cors');
  app.use(cors({origin:["localhost:4200"], credentials: true}))
```

Error Message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:5000/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `cors` package documentation:

"Certain CORS requests are considered 'complex' and require an initial OPTIONS request (called the "pre-flight request"). An example of a 'complex' CORS request is one that uses an HTTP verb other than GET/HEAD/POST (such as DELETE) or that uses custom headers. To enable pre-flighting, you must add a new OPTIONS handler for the route you want to support."

If you want to use the `cors` package, you need to add an OPTIONS handler for any route that needs one (i.e. any route the browser will call). Otherwise, you can manually handle app-wide CORS manually, by adding the required headers to the request.